# Unable to turn off the airplane mode and wifi is not working ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, lts, 20.04, airplane-mode

Hi I just switched from windows 10 to Ubuntu. I have HP Probook 4540s and it has wireless button but it seems like it is not working as I am unable to turn off the airplane mode and cannot connect to WiFi.

The output for `iwconfig` is:

```
enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

and the output for `lspci -nnk | grep -EA3 Ralink` is

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:539a]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1839]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
```

Please help me as I am unable to do any work without internet... Thank you in advance!